# How to getchildren in Zookeeper based on a filtering?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

**Use case:** 
Get children of a parent only if some of its stat value matches our condition.

example:

```
parentnode of P:
  c1 (stat.datalength 100)
  c2 (stat.datalength 3340)
  c3 (stat.datalength 2561) 
  c4 (stat.datalength 1000)
  c5 (stat.datalength 456)
```

Get only those children ***where datalength > 1024***.
**Result** should return only c2 and c3.

The documentation doesnt say anything about it:
https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html

edit: get all children then traversing it and applying the filter by hand is big overhead in performance-wise.

Comment: Is it such a big overhead to get the list of children paths, then call stat on each to get their data length and just keep those paths that satisfy your requirement? This does not actually traverse each of the children znode data just its metadata stored in ZooKeeper namespace. 
Anyway, I think there is no other alternative.